# Pivot orientation single into multiple column

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

```
This is the layout I want:         but this is what currently I get:
```

[image: Orientation Wanted]
[image: Orientation Need To Change]

from this code:

```
Private Sub KPIDashboardTable()
Sheets("KPI Dashboard List").Activate
Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField, Ws As Worksheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("KPI Dashboard List").Range("A1").Select

Set Ws = Sheets.Add
Ws.Name = "KPI Dashboard List Table"

Set objTable = Sheets("KPI Dashboard List").PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=Ws.Cells(3, "A"))
objTable.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlmissingItemNone
objTable.PivotCache.Refresh

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("DATE OPENED")
objField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("KPI")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField
objField.Function = xlSum
objField.Position = 1

Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("KPI")
objField.Orientation = xlDataField

Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("DATE OPENED")
pf.DataRange.Cells(1).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, _
False, False, True, False, False)

Range("B2").Value = "KPI Dashboard"
Range("A2:O2").Font.Bold = True
Range("A2:O2").Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

How can I change the orientation of the PivotTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
With objTable.DataPivotField
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
```